# What does "expression must be a modifiable lvalue" mean?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
int x;
(rand() % 100) + 1 = x;
```

It keeps saying:

> expression should be a modifiable lvalue

Comment: What does this (rand() % 100) + 1 = x; mean?

Comment: `(rand() % 100) + 1 = x;` makes no sense. You are assigning the value of `x` to some temporary thing that you can never again get hold of. That's pointless (at best).

Answer (score 3):

Left and right operands of `=` are not interchangable.

It's the left operand that's being *assigned to*, so it has to be assignable.

Given `int x;`, `x` is assignable (a 'modifiable lvalue'), but `x + 42` is not (an rvalue).

Answer (score 2):

It means that you've put the wrong things on each side of the assignment operator (`=`). The expression on the left should be something you can assign a value to (the "l" in "lvalue" stands for "left"), and the expression on the right should compute the value you want to assign.

Try

```
x = (rand() % 100) + 1;
```

instead.

Answer (score 2):

The lvalue always has to be a changeable/modifiable one. 
So you can't do :

```
int a ;
3 = a ;
```

This means that you are trying to change `3` to `a` which is not possible because `3` is a constant.

So similarily,
Do this :

```
x = (rand() % 100) + 1;
```

And, the error should be gone.